# Setting zindex for rectangle on canvas is not bringing it to front

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, z-index

I've got a problem with canvas and rectangles painted on it.
They are gaining events in reversed order of creation (newest is on top), not the order of zindex...

I've got ItemsControl binded with list of resources.

Then there is a canvas as item panel:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Canvas x:Name="BitmapCanvas"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

All resources are binded as rectangles:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="interfaces:IResourceView">
        <Rectangle ...>
```

and there is a style:

```
<Rectangle.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.ZIndex" Value="0"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.ZIndex" Value="15"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    ...</Rectangle.Style></Rectangle></DataTemplate></ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

As you can see, when the rectangle is selected, I'm setting its Zindex to 0, and others have then zindex value bigger. I was trying it also with swapped values, but still 
rectangles are gaining focus in the same way.
Have anybody got an idea why it is happening like this?

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but I'm wondering why you have your Style in Rectangle.Style instead of in ItemsControl.Resources or some other Resources tag higher up the tree.

Comment: This is my own class Rectangle which implements INotifyPropertyChanged.
The best thing in this problem is that this ZIndex is setting properly. I'm logging it when MouseMove event is raised.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're doing now.

Comment: Binded IsSelected property is from IResourceView.
Rectangle is from windows.shapes
My own Rectangle class with INotifyPropertyChanged is "hidden" in IResourceView ;)
All styles are working, on data trigger which checks "true" value there ale also other setters, which are working properly too...

Comment: I'm sure you've done this already, but have you verified that you are firing NotifyPropertyChanged whenever IsSelected property is set (assuming IsSelected is defined in your custom Rectangle.  i.e. `If (PropertyChanged!=null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsSelected");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `Canvas.ZIndex` (or actually [Panel.ZIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex.aspx) in WPF) on the Rectangle in the DataTemplate has no effect, since those Rectangles are no direct children of the Canvas in the ItemsPanelTemplate. In other words, the Rectangles are no siblings, but `ZIndex` is a relative value the only affects the siblings of the same container control.

Actually each rectangle is put into the Content of a ContentPresenter (which is the item container type of an ItemsControl). These ContentPresenters are then put into the Canvas.

To get things working, you may move the DataTriggers to the [ItemContainerStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx):

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="0"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="15"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: However, your ZIndex values suggest that the selected item should be behind the others, as 0 is lower than 15.

Answer (score 0):

You issue is with your Triggers. Style only supports EventTrigger, not any of the other types so your Triggers will never be executed. You are in a DataTemplate though, and those do support DataTrigger so you can move some things around to fix the issue:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Rect"/>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Rect" Property="Canvas.ZIndex" Value="0"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="false">
                <Setter TargetName="Rect" Property="Canvas.ZIndex" Value="15"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: `ZIndex` will still be ineffective if set on the Rectangle. It must be set on the ContentPresenter.

Comment: And DataTrigger still won't work in a Style, no matter what type you set it on.

Comment: @JohnBowen "Style only supports EventTrigger". Where do you get that from? Perhaps some old WPF version?